# pandas convert comma to dash inside parentheses

Tags: python, pandas

given a data set that has commas as part of the text, is there a good/easy way to convert them so i can parse the rest of the data using the 'real' commas?
the commas I want to ignore/translate are always inside parentheses

```
#Create Series
s = pd.Series(['one,two,ten','first,second,third(twenty,thirty,forty),last','ten,eleven,twelve'],['buz','bas','bur'])
k = pd.Series(['y','n','o'],['buz','bas','bur'])

#Create DataFrame df from two series
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':s,'second':k})
```

my thought is that for each row in column first I need to check for a "(" and then if there is a "," convert it to "-".  then if I get to the ")" I stop the translation.
In the end I will have third(twenty-thirty-forty)

Is there a char by char parser that can be triggered by a "("

expected output:

```
#Create Series
s = pd.Series(['one,two,ten','first,second,third(twenty-thirty-forty),last','ten,eleven,twelve'],['buz','bas','bur'])
k = pd.Series(['y','n','o'],['buz','bas','bur'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':s,'second':k})
```

Comment: please share an example of your expected output

Comment: I did.  instead of third(twenty,thirty,forty); i need it to be third(twenty-thirty-forty)

Comment: added to the original for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try **[`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)** with **replacement lambda function**

```
repl = lambda g: g.group().replace(',', '-')
df['first'] = df['first'].str.replace(r'\(.*?\)', repl, regex=True)
```

Regex details

- `\(`: Matches the character `(`
- `.*?`: Matches any character zero or more times but as few times as possible (lazy match)
- `\)`: Matches the character `)`

See the [`online regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/2DsfVH/1)

Result

```
print(df)

                                            first second
buz                                   one,two,ten      y
bas  first,second,third(twenty-thirty-forty),last      n
bur                             ten,eleven,twelve      o
```

Comment: first time i've seen `str.replace` with a callable, very nice!

Comment: it works! thank you.  i understand most of it, but a bit confused on   r'\((.*?)\)'     could you break that down for me?

Comment: @kdot I've edited the answer with explanation of regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a character by character parser and apply to each column:

```
def replace_comma(x):
    # create a list from the string
    x_list = [s for s in x]

    # create a second list to modify
    new_xlist = x_list

    # set a flag for when in paranthesis
    in_paranthesis = False

    # iterate through the list
    for count, character in enumerate(x_list):
        if character == '(':
            in_paranthesis = True
        elif character == ')':
            in_paranthesis = False
        elif character == ',' and in_paranthesis is True:
            # if in paranthesis, replace comma with '/'
            new_xlist[count] = '/'

    # return new_xlist, with /'s, joined as a string
    return ('').join(new_xlist)
```

Use pandas apply on each column:

```
df = df['first'].apply(replace_comma)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and regex.

```
df['first'].str.replace(r"(,(?=[^()]*\)))", '-')
```

---

```
Output:
buz                                     one,two,ten
bas    first,second,third(twenty-thirty-forty),last
bur                               ten,eleven,twelve
Name: first, dtype: object
```